# How to move files by extension using Puppet

Tags: puppet

I want to move files by extension.

1) Do I really have to create the files and delete after the copy or can I do that in a single task?

2) What if I want to copy *.jpg files to folder files/jpg/ and *.htm files to files/htm? How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to move files by extension.

Although Puppet can help you do this, it is not what Puppet is designed for.  Puppet provides a machine-state management service.  Everything it does should be construed in the context of this decision tree:

- What is the desired target state?
- Is the machine already in the target state?

  - Yes: do nothing.
  - No: update the machine to be in the target state

Puppet is not a script engine, and Puppet manifests should not be regarded as scripts.

> 1) Do I really have to create the files and delete after the copy or can I do that in a single task?

No and yes, respectively. Although Puppet is not a script engine, it *can* execute arbitrary programs (including scripts) and shell commands for you.  This is provided via the core [`Exec` resource type](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.1/types/exec.html).  This will work best for you if you conceptualize your task in terms of a target state -- as opposed to a desired action -- and write your code from that perspective, but you should be able to proceed even if that seems obscure.

> 2) What if I want to copy *.jpg files to folder files/jpg/ and *.htm
>   files to files/htm? How can I do that?

How would you do it from the command line?  Notwithstanding the conceptualization issue, the nuts and bolts are that you would apply an `Exec` resource whose `command` parameter is a shell command that does the job, either directly or via a script.

Or if you succeeded in couching the objective in terms of a resource to be managed into a specific state, *and* you were an overachiever with time on your hands, then you might consider encapsulating that in [a custom resource type](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.0/custom_resources.html), an instance of which you could use in place of a generic `Exec`.